# Unable to run spark-submit on a spark cluster running in docker container

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark

I have a set up of spark cluster running on docker in which the following things are running:-

1. spark-master
2. three spark-workers (spark-worker-1, spark-worker-2, spark-worker-3)

For setting up the spark cluster I have followed the instructions given on URL:-
 https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark

Now I want to launch a spark application which can run on this cluster and for this, I am using bde2020/spark-scala-template and following the instructions given on URL:-
 https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark/tree/master/template/scala

But when I tried to run the jar file then it starts running on the spark master present in the bde2020/spark-scala-template image and not on the master of my cluster running in a different container.

Please help me to do that. Stucked very badly.

Comment: How are you mentioning master or resource manager in your spark submit command?